# shared preferences doesn't work to store checkbox selected

Tags: android, listview, android-fragments, checkbox, android-sharedpreferences

When I check a checkbox in a list view with checkbox and after I change list view clicked on another tab, if I comeback to previous tab, the checkbox before checked, now is not checked.... So, how can i maintain checkbox checked when I change tab and after I comeback to previous tab? THANKS IN ADVANCE!

this is my code....

ADAPTER:

```
        public abstract class PlanetAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Planet> implements CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener

        {

            private List<Planet> planetList=null;
            private Context context=null;
            ArrayList<Birra> objects;
            private HashMap<Integer, Planet> pizzaSelected = new HashMap<>();
            public boolean Checked;

            public  PlanetAdapter(List<Planet> planetList, Context context) {

                super(context, R.layout.single_listview_item, planetList);
                this.planetList = planetList;
                this.context = context;
            }


            public  class PlanetHolder  {
                public TextView planetName;
                public TextView distView;
                public TextView valuta;
                public CheckBox chkBox;
                public EditText edit;
                //public String quantità;
                public boolean checked;
                public TextView id;
            }
            @Override
            public int getCount() {
                return planetList.size();
            }

            @Override
            public Planet getItem(int position) {
                return planetList.get(position);
            }

            @Override
            public long getItemId(int position) {
                return planetList.get(position).getId();
            }


            @Override
            public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

                View row = convertView;
                PlanetHolder holder = null;

                if (row == null) {
                    LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity) context).getLayoutInflater();
                    row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.single_listview_item, parent, false);
                    holder = new PlanetHolder();
                    holder.planetName = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.name);
                    holder.distView = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.dist);
                    holder.valuta = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.valuta);
                    holder.chkBox = (CheckBox) row.findViewById(R.id.chk_box);
                    holder.edit = (EditText) row.findViewById(R.id.editText);
                    holder.edit.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    holder.edit.setEnabled(false);
                    holder.id = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.id);


                    row.setTag(holder);

                } else {
                    holder = (PlanetHolder) row.getTag();
                }
                final Planet p = planetList.get(position);
                SharedPreferences states = getContext().getSharedPreferences("states", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
                boolean isChecked = states.getBoolean("holder.chkBox"+holder.planetName.getText().toString(), false);
                System.out.println(isChecked);
                if(isChecked) {
                    holder.chkBox.setChecked(true);
                } else {
                    holder.chkBox.setChecked(false);
                }

     final PlanetHolder finalHolder = holder;




            holder.chkBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
                @Override
                public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                    if (finalHolder.chkBox.isChecked()) {
                        finalHolder.edit.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        finalHolder.edit.setEnabled(true);
                        SharedPreferences states = getContext().getSharedPreferences("states", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
                        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = states.edit();
                        editor.putBoolean("holder.chkBox"+finalHolder.planetName.getText().toString(), true);



                    } else {
                        SharedPreferences states = getContext().getSharedPreferences("states", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
                        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = states.edit();
                        finalHolder.edit.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        finalHolder.edit.setEnabled(false);
                        finalHolder.edit.setText("");
                        editor.putBoolean("holder.chkBox" , false);

                    }
                    SharedPreferences states = getContext().getSharedPreferences("states", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
                    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = states.edit();
                    editor.commit();
                    System.out.println(editor.commit());
                }
            });

     finalHolder.edit.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
                @Override
                public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
                }

                @Override
                public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
                }

                @Override
                public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
                    p.setQuantità(finalHolder.edit.getText().toString().trim());


                }
            });


                    holder.planetName.setText(p.getName());
                    holder.distView.setText("" + p.getDistance());
                    holder.valuta.setText("" + p.getValuta());
                    holder.chkBox.setChecked(p.isSelected());
                    holder.chkBox.setTag(p);
                    holder.edit.setEnabled(false);
                  //  holder.id.setId(p.getId());


            return row;
                }

                ArrayList<Planet> getBox() {
                    ArrayList<Planet> box = new ArrayList<Planet>();
                    for (Planet p : planetList) {
                        if (p.selected)
                            box.add(p);
                    }
                    return box;
                }

            }

FRAGMENT:

    public class MyListFragment extends Fragment implements
            android.widget.CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener {

        ListView lv;
        ArrayList<Planet> planetList;
        PlanetAdapter plAdapter;
        BirraAdapter biAdapter;
        PlanetAdapter.PlanetHolder holder;




        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                                 Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            // Inflate the layout for this fragment

            ViewGroup rootView = (ViewGroup) inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_list2, container, false);

            Button mButton = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.button);
            mButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    showResult(v);


                }
            });
            //return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_list2, container, false);
            return rootView;
        }


        @Override
        public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);


            lv = (ListView)getView().findViewById(R.id.listview);
            displayPlanetList();


        }


        private void displayPlanetList() {

            planetList = new ArrayList<Planet>();
            planetList.add(new Planet("Margherita", 6, "€",1));
            planetList.add(new Planet("Diavola", 7,"€",2));
            planetList.add(new Planet("Bufalina", 5,"€",3));
            planetList.add(new Planet("Marinara", 5, "€",4));
            planetList.add(new Planet("Viennese", 4, "€",5));

            plAdapter = new PlanetAdapter(planetList, getContext()) {
                @Override
                public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {

                    int pos = lv.getPositionForView(buttonView);
                    if (pos != ListView.INVALID_POSITION) {
                        Planet p = planetList.get(pos);
                        p.setSelected(isChecked);


                /*Toast.makeText(
                    getActivity(),
                    "Clicked on Pizza: " + p.getName() + ". State: is "
                            + isChecked, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();*/
                    }


                }
            };

            lv.setAdapter(plAdapter);
            //plAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }



        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {

            /*int pos = lv.getPositionForView(buttonView);
            if (pos != ListView.INVALID_POSITION) {
                Planet p = planetList.get(pos);
                p.setSelected(isChecked);


                *//*Toast.makeText(
                    getActivity(),
                    "Clicked on Planet: " + p.getName() + ". State: is "
                            + isChecked, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();*//*
            }*/

        }


        public void showResult(View v) {
            String  result2 = "Selected Product are :";
            int totalAmount2=0;

            String a="";
            for (Birra b : biAdapter.getBox()){

                if (b.selected){

                    result2 += "\n" + b.name+" "+b.distance+"€"+"q.tà :"+b.getQuantità();
                    int quantitaInt= Integer.parseInt(b.getQuantità());
                    totalAmount2+=b.distance * quantitaInt;
                    //a=String.valueOf(totalAmount);


                }
            }
        /*  for (Planet p : plAdapter.getBox()) {
                if (p.selected){

                    result += "\n" + p.name+" "+p.distance+"€"+"q.tà :"+p.getQuantità();
                    int quantitaInt= Integer.parseInt(p.getQuantità() );
                    totalAmount+=p.distance * quantitaInt;
                    //a=String.valueOf(totalAmount);


                }
            }*/
          //Toast.makeText(getActivity(), result + "\n" + "Total Amount:=" + totalAmount + "€", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), result2 + "\n" + "Total Amount:=" + totalAmount2 + "€", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            /*Bundle bun2 = new Bundle();
            bun2.putString("scelta", result);
            TwoFragment fgsearch2 = new TwoFragment();
            fgsearch2.setArguments(bun2);
            android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction transaction2 = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            transaction2.replace(R.id.content_main, fgsearch2);
            transaction2.commit();


            Bundle bun = new Bundle();
            bun.putString("totale", a);
            TwoFragment fgsearch = new TwoFragment();
            fgsearch.setArguments(bun);
            android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction transaction = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            transaction.replace(R.id.content_main2, fgsearch);
            transaction.commit();
    */
```

*MAIN:*

MAIN:

```
public class Main extends AppCompatActivity{



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().

                replace(R.id.fragmentContainer, new MyListFragment()).commit();



    }


    @Override protected void onDestroy() {
        SharedPreferences preferences=getSharedPreferences("states", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor=preferences.edit();
        editor.clear().apply();
        super.onDestroy();
    }

}









        }
```

Comment: In your `OnCheckedChangeListener` you are writing `editor.putBoolean("holder.chkBox" , false);` if the state changed to `checked == false` ... but i think this should be `editor.putBoolean("holder.chkBox"+finalHolder.planetName.getText().toString(), false);` this could be one possible error...

Comment: You forgot to commit your `editor` after `putBoolean` into it. You `committed`  the different `Editor`.

Comment: i write editor.putBoolean("holder.chkBox"+finalHolder.planetName.getText().toString(), false); but doesn't work..

Comment: of course, because you dont commit it after putBoolean. Remember that `states.edit();` will create new `Editor`. You tried to save new created `Editor` that makes no sense.

Comment: yes, of course it's not work. Because of your `holder.chkBox.setChecked(p.isSelected());`. That makes all your top `SharedPreferences` makes no sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your getView(), I think you should call apply() instead of commit to save values to sharedPreferences; apply saves immediately. Also, you should set values to holder.planetName before using it as key in sharedPreferences.

Check this out:

```
@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    View row = convertView;
    PlanetHolder holder = null;

    if (row == null) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity) context).getLayoutInflater();
        row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.single_listview_item, parent, false);
        holder = new PlanetHolder();
        holder.planetName = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.name);
        holder.distView = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.dist);
        holder.valuta = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.valuta);
        holder.chkBox = (CheckBox) row.findViewById(R.id.chk_box);
        holder.edit = (EditText) row.findViewById(R.id.editText);
        holder.edit.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        holder.edit.setEnabled(false);
        holder.id = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.id);


        row.setTag(holder);

    } else {
        holder = (PlanetHolder) row.getTag();
    }

    final Planet p = planetList.get(position);
    // I think you should set a value to holder.planetName before using the value as
    // preference key
    holder.planetName.setText(p.getName());
    holder.distView.setText("" + p.getDistance());
    holder.valuta.setText("" + p.getValuta());
    holder.chkBox.setChecked(p.isSelected());
    holder.chkBox.setTag(p);
    holder.edit.setEnabled(false);
    //  holder.id.setId(p.getId());

    SharedPreferences states = getContext().getSharedPreferences("states", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    boolean isChecked = states.getBoolean("holder.chkBox"+holder.planetName.getText().toString(), false);
    System.out.println(isChecked);
    if(isChecked) {
        holder.chkBox.setChecked(true);
    } else {
        holder.chkBox.setChecked(false);
    }

    final PlanetHolder finalHolder = holder;




    holder.chkBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
            if (finalHolder.chkBox.isChecked()) {
                finalHolder.edit.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                finalHolder.edit.setEnabled(true);
                SharedPreferences states = getContext().getSharedPreferences("states", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
                SharedPreferences.Editor editor = states.edit();
                editor.putBoolean("holder.chkBox"+finalHolder.planetName.getText().toString()
                        , true);



            } else {
                SharedPreferences states = getContext().getSharedPreferences("states", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
                SharedPreferences.Editor editor = states.edit();
                finalHolder.edit.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                finalHolder.edit.setEnabled(false);
                finalHolder.edit.setText("");
                editor.putBoolean("holder.chkBox" , false);

            }
            SharedPreferences states = getContext().getSharedPreferences("states", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = states.edit();
            editor.apply();
            System.out.println(editor.commit());
        }
    });

    finalHolder.edit.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            p.setQuantità(finalHolder.edit.getText().toString().trim());


        }
    });




    return row;
}
```

Comment: every new run i want checkbox not checked

Comment: Note that SharedPreferences is used to save data across sessions hence even after you close the app and open later, the data still persists. That aside, to achieve your required functionlaity,add this to the onDestroy of your activity `SharedPreferences preferences=getSharedPreferences("states", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor=preferences.edit();
        editor.clear().apply();`

Comment: where i must put the method "onDestroy"? in onCreate of my fragment?

Comment: No. Fragments can destroyed and recreated several times in one app session. Add it to the onDestroy of the last activity your app would show before exiting

Comment: sorry, can you make an example with my code?please?

Comment: in your last activity, paste this: `@Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        SharedPreferences preferences=getSharedPreferences("states", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor=preferences.edit();
        editor.clear().apply();
        super.onDestroy();
    }`

Comment: at the end of my adapter where i use shared preferences i must use method onDestroy? in what sense in last activity?

Comment: your adapter is bound to an activity. Assuming you have just one activity in your app, then inside the activity, copy the above code and paste there. **onDestroy** is the last callback your activity would make before it is discarded completely. **NOTE** your adapter is not an activity, in case you are in doubt of what an activity is, check [this](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities.html), also [this](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/index.html) for activity lifecycles to understand how onDestroy is called

Comment: 5 minutes and i will edit code, so you can see if i write in good way the method destroy

Comment: ok, now you can see in "FRAGMENT" if i put in good way "onDestroy"

Comment: Dont put it inside a fragment, fragments can be destroyed several times in one app session. Add it in your activity

Comment: i put method onDestroy before method onCreate in main class where i call fragment...but doesn't work..

Comment: i edited code adding method onDestroy()...can you see if i write method in good way?

Comment: how many activities do you have in your app? Put this log message in the onDestroy of all your activities: `Log.e("OnDestroy"," callback_1"); ... Log.e("OnDestroy"," callback_n");` i.e if you have 3 activites, the first, 2nd and 3rd would contain in their onDestroy(): `Log.e("OnDestroy"," callback_1"); , Log.e("OnDestroy"," callback_2"); , Log.e("OnDestroy"," callback_3");` , after that, run the app again then watch the log for the one that would be called last when you kill the app. **NOTE** to kill the app, you have to open the recently opened app menu and swipe it(the app) off

Comment: ok, it is ok now.....but now i have another problem....can help me please?i link you my question :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37305687/class-adapter-doesnt-work

Answer (score 0):

Just change your **OnCheckedChangeListener** code as below. You were not committing after change:

```
 holder.chkBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
            if (finalHolder.chkBox.isChecked()) {
                finalHolder.edit.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                finalHolder.edit.setEnabled(true);
                SharedPreferences states = getContext().getSharedPreferences("states", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
                SharedPreferences.Editor editor = states.edit();
                editor.putBoolean("holder.chkBox"+finalHolder.planetName.getText().toString(), true);
                editor.commit();


            } else {
                SharedPreferences states = getContext().getSharedPreferences("states", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
                SharedPreferences.Editor editor = states.edit();
                finalHolder.edit.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                finalHolder.edit.setEnabled(false);
                finalHolder.edit.setText("");
                editor.putBoolean("holder.chkBox"+finalHolder.planetName.getText().toString() , false);
                editor.commit();
            }
        }
    });
```

This will work. :)

Comment: System.out.println(isChecked); and in consolle i have false...but not set true the checkbox

Answer (score 0):

You are re-initializing SharedPreferences states it should be done once on before it get to getView. You can do that in the constructor of PlanetAdapter.

Comment: but if i put getBoolean into construction, the object holder into construction is not visible

Comment: not getBoolean. SharedPreferences states  will be a global varaible

Comment: okay check this out.  public  PlanetAdapter(List<Planet> planetList, Context context) {

            super(context, R.layout.single_listview_item, planetList);
            this.planetList = planetList;
            this.context = context; states = context.getSharedPreferences("states", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        }